# Were did I go wrong in my basic algebra?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Solving for variable $d$:

$v = \frac{1}{2}hd^2 + 9.9$

$-2(v - 9.9) = hd^2$

$-2v + 19.8 = hd^2$

$d = \sqrt{\frac{-2v + 19.8}{h}}$

The correct answer is:

$d = \pm\sqrt{\frac{2v - 19.8}{h}}$

Answer (score 1):

From $$V = \frac{1}{2}hd^2 + 9.9$$ you may deduce, with appropriate conditions:
$$
2V = hd^2 + 2\times9.9
$$ $$
2V-19.8 = hd^2
$$$$
\frac{2V-19.8}h = d^2
$$$$
 \pm\sqrt{\frac{2V-19.8}h }= d.
$$

Comment: Thank you. Did the $\pm$ come from the squareroot sign?

Comment: @Intimate_Guest Yes! Sorry, I initially tought $d\geq0$. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

$$V = \frac{1}{2}hd^2 + 9.9$$

Subtract 9.9 to the LHS and multiply everything by 2

$$2(V-9.9) = hd^2$$

1) Divide by $h$ (likely the height in the problem)

2) Solve for $d$ by taking the square root of both sides